# IE 8 will no longer accept cookies from localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, session-cookies

I had to disable cookies for some testing in a web application.  now for some reason in IE I cannot get cookies working on localhost any more. They work as expected in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, but for some unknown reason I cannot for the life of me get cookies working on localhost. I have tried literally every setting imaginable with absolutely no luck.  If I change the Url to 'localhost." it works as expected, but when I just use "localhost", without the "." period, cookies are absolutely not written. What the heck did i do? I tried upgrading to IE 9 and that didn't work. I reverted back to IE 8 and still have the same problem.  I'm going absolutely mad trying to firgure out what is causing this.  I tried tools, internet options, privacy, advanced, and explicit tell the browser to accept all 1st and 3rd party cookies and I'll be damned if I'm on a localhost site, the cookies are not written.  This has worked perfect in the past, so it's no doubt some setting I changed but I cannot for the life of me figure out what the hell is going on. If anyone has any idea of how I can remedy this, please do let me know.  I've tried every setting imaginable with absolutely no luck.  I hate internet explorer but that a conversation for a different day.

Comment: Find and clear the cookies for the localhost

Comment: +1 about IE hating. urrrr

Comment: Funny, I have the opposite problem with IE11. I can not disable cookies for localhost. I set the slider to max (Block All Cookies) but they still are used for localhost. I resorted to address the web page as hxxps://127.0.0.1 and then it worked. One more note: "localhost" can not be added to the list of blocked/allowed sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go into tools, internet options, advanced, and hit the reset button. Put everything back to factory defaults :)

Answer (score 3):

At my wit's end, I just decided to try using http://127.0.0.1/... instead of http://localhost/....   It works.  Had a similar problem with Safari and same solution worked there.  Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Were you by chance using a tool like Fiddler2?  Check your connection settings etc... I have had IE get hung in a weird state after using web proxy tools.

Answer (score 0):

@Hcabnettek try to set IE caching settings to `Always Refresh from server` in `Developer Tools`.

That might be problem and also try adding one extra querystring containing some random values to your page URL every time because you can never be sure about cache is enabled or disabled at client side, so adding random values in URL's querystring will trigger IE to load new cache for that different page URL.

Hope that helps you, because it helped me also.